# Resolve undefined reference by stripping unused code

Tags: c, undefined-reference, dead-code

Assume we have the following C code:

```c
void undefined_reference(void);

void bad(void) {
    undefined_reference();
}

int main(void) {}
```

In function `bad` we fall into the linker error `undefined reference to 'undefined_reference'`, as expected. This function is not actually used anywhere in the code, though, and as such, for the execution of the program, this undefined reference doesn't matter.

Is it possible to compile this code successfully, such that `bad` simply gets removed as it is never called (similar to tree-shaking in JavaScript)?

Comment: There are linkers that strip dead code, in conjunction with compiler support, so it may be possible to compile and link this code successfully with the right tools. But you have not indicated which tools you are using or are interested in. As a matter of theory, yes, this is possible. As a matter of what can be accomplishing using only features specified by the C standard, no, it is not possible to guarantee successful compiling and linking. For a specific answer between those, you need to identify the tools to be used.

Comment: You could also do other weird tricks, such as exporting `undefined_reference` symbol from a linker script. But why? Just delete the dead code.

Comment: Removing the [tree-shaking] tag, since that is associated specifically with ECMAscript, and the question is about C.

Comment: You could put `bad` into an object file in a library and link the program with the library so that the object file containing `bad` only gets linked in if something needs it.

Comment: @IanAbbott Did you mean the `undefined_reference()` ? I guess `bad()` is "fixed"

Comment: @EugeneSh. I *do* mean moving `bad()` into a library. If something outside the library calls `bad()` (perhaps indirectly from some other function in the library) then something will also need to provide an external definition of `undefined_reference()`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Or to be more accurate, if something outside the library *refers* to the `bad()` function (not necessarily *call* it) (perhaps indirectly) then something will also need to define `undefined_reference()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This function is not actually used anywhere in the code!*

You know that, I know that, but the compiler doesn't. It deals with one translation unit at a time. It cannot divine out that there are no other translation units.

*But `main` doesn't call anything, so there cannot be other translation units!*

There can be code that runs before and after `main` (in an implementation-defined manner).

*OK what about the linker? It sees the whole program!*

Not really. Code can be loaded dynamically at run time (also by code that the linker cannot see).

So neither the compiler nor linker even try to find unused function *by default*.

On some systems it is possible to instruct the compiler and the linker to try and garbage-collect unused code (and assume a whole-program view when doing so), but this is not usually the default mode of operation.

With gcc and gnu ld, you can use these options:

```
gcc -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections main.c -o main
```

Other systems may have different ways of doing this.

Comment: The linker, in most cases, is able to eliminate unused *sections*. I am not sure what is the default here, but it is also able to place each function in a separate section (in fact it is the compiler who can). So with these two abilities it can (and will) eliminate unused functions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Added options that enable this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Many compilers (for example gcc) will compile and link it correctly if you

1. Enable optimizations
2. make function `bad` `static`. Otherwise, it will have external linkage.

https://godbolt.org/z/KrvfrYYdn

Another way is to add the stump version of this function (and pragma displaying warning)

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this in production code though...

Comment: @EugeneSh. me too ....

Comment: However, if `bad()` is not already static then this requires modifying the source, and if you're willing and able to do that then you might as well just remove the function altogether or suppress its definition via conditional compilation directives.